# How to get the six week sunday's weekno in SQL server 2008 r2?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, sql-server-2008-r2

I want to get the six week sundays weekno using the SQL Server 2008.For example i have the November month, date 18, year 2012. The WeekNo of the  November month 18 th date is "47".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this:

```
SELECT DATEPART(week,'18-nov-2012')
```

Comment: i need to start the date as sunday.Is it suitable for my criteria ?

Comment: @AdalarasanSachithanantham: what do you mean by 'start the date as sunday' ?

Comment: set datefirst 1 means it take sunday as 1

Comment: datefirst 1 - means sunday, 2- means monday,3 - means tuesday,4- means wednesday, 5- means thursday, 6- friday, 7- saturday

Comment: Are you trying to create a manual date regardless of what it is. Like 1-jan-2013 is Tuesday,but yow want it as Sunday.
If so, where do you need it?

Comment: i'm just curious. But i need the start date as sunday.It works fine..why because it's suitable for my need

Comment: SET DATEFIRST 7; 
1-mon,2-tues,3-wed,4-thurs,5-fri,6-sat,7-sun(default,for US)

   for more help :

msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms181598.aspx